# The area of $\triangle AMN$ where $MN$ is midsegment

Tags: geometry, triangles

$M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $AC$. If the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $24$ $cm^2,$ what is the area of $\triangle AMN$?

[image]

We can say for sure that $MN\parallel BC$ and $MN=\dfrac12 BC$. I don't know what to do next. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: similar triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $$S_\triangle = \frac{1}{2}ab\sin\alpha$$
where $a$ and $b$ are sides and $\alpha$ the angle between them. Using this, we have
$$\frac{S_{ABC}}{S_{AMN}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \color{red}{AB}\cdot \color{blue}{AC}\cdot \sin\alpha}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \color{red}{AM}\cdot \color{blue}{AN} \cdot \sin \alpha} = \color{red}{2}\cdot \color{blue}{2}=4 
 \Rightarrow S_{AMN} = \frac{S_{ABC}}{4} = \frac{24}{4} = 6$$
after some cancellations.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Draw a line from N parallel with AB. Draw another from M parallel with AC. Now you have four  triangles. All you have to do is to prove they are equal and conclude that the area is one fourth of area of triangle ABC.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   \angle A &\equiv \angle A \\
   AN &= \frac 12 AC \\
   AM &= \frac 12 AB \\
\hline
   \triangle ANM &\sim \triangle ACB &\{\text{By SAS}\}
\end{align}

$$\therefore\dfrac{|\triangle ANM|}{|\triangle ACB|} = \left(\dfrac{AN}{AC}\right)^2 $$

$$\dfrac{|\triangle ANM|}{24} = \dfrac 14$$

$$|\triangle ANM| = 6$$